# Distribution of point-dependent function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I want to find the distribution function of $$(XY)^{-Z},$$ where $(X, Y, Z)$ are the coordinates of a point randomly selected from the cube $[0;1]^3$. I don't know how to solve it and how to start. Can you give me a hint, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that $X,Y,Z$ are independent random variables, uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$, we may first define $W=XY$, which is obviously supported on $[0,1]$, and find the PDF of $W$. For any $k\in(0,1)$ we have

$$ \mathbb{P}[W<k]=\int_{0}^{1}\mathbb{P}[X<k/u]\,du =k-k\log k$$
hence the PDF of $W$ is $f_W(k)=\frac{d}{dk}(k-k\log k)=-\log(k)$. We apply the same approach to $W^{-Z}$, which is supported on $(1,+\infty)$. For any $k>1$

$$ \mathbb{P}[W^{-Z}<k]=\mathbb{P}[W^Z>\frac{1}{k}]=\int_{0}^{1}-\log(u)\mathbb{P}[Z<-\frac{\log k}{\log u}]\,du $$
$$ \mathbb{P}[W^{-Z}<k]=\int_{0}^{1/k}\log(k)\,du+\int_{1/k}^{1}-\log(u)\,du $$
$$ \mathbb{P}[W^{-Z}<k]=\frac{\log k}{k}+1-\frac{1+\log k}{k}=1-\frac{1}{k}$$
hence the PDF of $XY^{-Z}$ simply is $\frac{1}{k^2}$.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain to me, what is "u"? And why is there "k/u"?

Comment: Ah, I understand. But cannot understand why is there logarithm ratio

Comment: @Deepest: $W^Z>\frac{1}{k}$ is equivalent to $Z\log(W)>-\log(k)$ and to $Z<-\frac{\log k}{\log W}$ (since $\log W$ is negative). The distrubution of $W$ is computed in the first lines (leading to the $-\log(u)$ factor inside the integral giving the CDF of $W^{-Z}$) and the remaining part are just straightforward computations.

Comment: I see why Z< -log(k)/log(W). But I still can’t understand how -log(u) became a factor inside the integral. Help, please. Only a step left to my understanding.

Comment: @Deepest: that $-\log(u)$ comes from the distribution of $W$ proved in the previous lines.

Comment: I'm completely confused. Could you describe the ellipsis part in more detail? $$\mathbb{P}[Z<-\frac{\log(k)}{\log(W)}]=...=\int_0^1−log(u)\mathbb{P}[Z<−\frac{log(k)}{log(u)}]du$$

Answer (score 0):

You need to compute the volume of the part of the cube where $(XY)^{-Z} < C$.

It will end up being a triple integral.  You integrate the value 1 and manipulate the bounds so that the equation is true.

Starting with $Z$:

$$(XY)^{-Z} < C$$
$$-Z\ln(XY) < \ln(C)$$
Direction reverses because $\ln(XY)$ is always negative.
$$-Z > \frac{\ln(C)}{\ln(XY)}$$
$$Z < \frac{-\ln(C)}{\ln(XY)}$$

So you have the bounds of Z in terms of C,X,Y.   Now you need to integrate for the $X,Y$ directions.